# Change Column Name in Select Based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have 2 tables

`DeductList`:

```
| DeID  | DeName | Deducts|
|   1   |  Late  |  $2.0  |
|   2   | No_IN  |  $1.0  |
|   3   | No_OUT |  $1.0  |
```

in DeductList Table, DeName is variable

`TransList`:

```
|TransID| TransDate  | EmpID | Deduct1 | Deduct2 | Deduct3 |
|   1   | 2019-12-01 |   20  |   $2.0  |   $0.0  |  $0.0   |
|   2   | 2019-12-02 |   27  |   $0.0  |   $1.0  |  $0.0   |
|   3   | 2019-12-03 |   25  |   $0.0  |   $0.0  |  $0.0   |
```

in TransList Table, I already have 3 Columns to store the Deducts values based on DeID

Now I want to select the TransList Table and JOIN with DeductList Table, so the results is

TransList Table with Deduct1, Deduct2, Deduct3 Column name is changed to DeName Based on DeID.
when Deduct1 then Dename with DeID 1, Deduct2 with DeID2, and so on.

here is the result I want when select TransList Table with JOIN to DeductList Table:

```
|TransID| TransDate  | EmpID |  Late   |  No_IN  |  No_OUT |
|   1   | 2019-12-01 |   20  |   $2.0  |   $0.0  |  $0.0   |
|   2   | 2019-12-02 |   27  |   $0.0  |   $1.0  |  $0.0   |
|   3   | 2019-12-03 |   25  |   $0.0  |   $0.0  |  $0.0   |
```

I really can't imagine the query, so can someone help me with the query? thank you for your kind help.

Comment: What are you expected results here? Your final result set looks to be the same as your second, just with Aliases. Is that all your question *really* is about?

Comment: yes, you're right, i want to select with alias for the TransList Table Based on DeductList Name.

Comment: Then just give the column an alias: `Deduct1 AS Late`  `Late = Deduct1`

Comment: The problem is: the alias is variable based on the DeductList Table, example: Deduct1 is Based on DeID 1 on DeductList Table so the column name is Late, if I change the Dename in table DeductLiast, so the Column Name on TransList Table must be changed too

Comment: You will have to use Dynamic SQL : build a SQL statement on a string variable, defining your desired aliases, and execute it using sp_executesql. https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1160/execute-dynamic-sql-commands-in-sql-server/

Comment: That article is *awful* @MarcGuillot . It's an Malicious person's SQL injection wet dream...

Comment: @Larnu, it covers the use of sp_executesql so you can protect your code from SQL injection, but you are right that it doesn't explain it. Although at the end of the article it links a couple other articles that explain the problems of Dynamic SQL and SQL injection and encourages us to read them.

Comment: @MarcGuillot `DECLARE @columnList varchar(75); SET @sqlCommand = 'SELECT ' + @columnList + ' FROM Person.Address WHERE City = ' + @city` is **not** injection safe in any shape of the phrase. That article doesn't mention `QUOTENAME` or checking the validity of the column name once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need dynamic sql to add column aliases based on the `DeductList` table.

For example:

```
DECLARE @DynSql NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Cols NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Cols = 'TransID, TransDate, EmpID ';

SELECT @Cols = CONCAT(@Cols,char(10),', Deduct',DeID,' AS ',QUOTENAME(DeName))
FROM DeductList 
WHERE DeID IN (1,2,3);

SET @DynSql = 'SELECT '
      + @Cols + char(10)
      + 'FROM TransList';

-- select @DynSql as DynSql;
EXECUTE sp_executesql @DynSql;
```

Will run the following SQL:

```
SELECT TransID, TransDate, EmpID 
, Deduct1 AS [Late]
, Deduct2 AS [No_IN]
, Deduct3 AS [No_OUT]
FROM TransList
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I tried your query, and it worked perfectly as I want.

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure how this can be translated into `SQL server` query but in `Oracle` i can use `recursion` and achieve the result as shown. See below and inline logic adopted. Request `SQL Server` enthusiast to implement the same logic.

IN `ORACLE`:

```
--Dataset Preparation
With tab (DeID,Dename) as (Select 1, 'Late' from dual
                           UNION ALL
                           Select 2, 'No_IN' from dual
                           UNION ALL
                           Select 3, 'No_OUT' from dual
                           ),
tab2(TransID ,TransDate,EmpID ,Deduct1,Deduct2,Deduct3) as (
                         Select 1,date '2019-12-01',20,'$2.0','$0.0','$0.0' from dual
                         UNION ALL
                         Select 2,date '2019-12-02',27,'$0.0','$1.0','$0.0' from dual
                         UNION ALL
                         Select 3,date '2019-12-03',25,'$0.0','$0.0','$0.0' from dual
                        ),
--Dataset Preparation End
    tab3 as (   --Joining 2 tables to fetch all records & Converting the row to columns
                SELECT *
                FROM tab 
                INNER JOIN tab2
                ON tab.deid   = tab2.transid                
                PIVOT ( MIN(1)
                    FOR dename
                    IN ( 'Late' as late,
                    'No_IN' as No_IN,
                    'No_OUT' as NO_OUT )
                )                
                )    
--Final Query to display the required result.             
Select  t.deid, 
        t.transdate,
        t.empid,
        case  when t.Late is null then t.Deduct1  else t.Deduct1 end Late ,
        case  when t.No_IN is null then t.Deduct2 else t.Deduct2 end No_IN,
        case  when t.No_OUT is null then t.Deduct3 else t.Deduct3 end No_OUT
from tab3 t  ;
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e1c50f03776d7b2ba890c61ecf46935c)

IN `SQLSERVER`

```
WITH tab AS
(
  SELECT * FROM DeductList
)
, tab2 AS
(
  SELECT * FROM TransList
)
, tab3 as
( --Joining 2 tables to fetch all records            
  SELECT *
  FROM tab 
  INNER JOIN tab2
  ON tab.deid = tab2.transid
  PIVOT ( 
    MIN(TransID)
    FOR dename IN ([Late], [No_IN], [No_OUT])
  ) pvt
)
--Final Query to display the required result.             
Select 
 t.deid, t.transdate, t.empid,
 case when t.Late is null then t.Deduct1 else t.Late end Late ,
 case when t.No_IN is null then t.Deduct2 else t.No_IN end No_IN,
 case  when t.No_OUT is null then t.Deduct3 else t.No_OUT end No_OUT
from tab3 t;
```

[SQLSERVER DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=f0ce4be936d88b941df6e9e6a3cb885a)

Thanks to @LukStorms for rewriting the query back to `SQLSERVER`

Comment: Fyi, such SQL would also run on MS Sql Server without all the `FROM DUAL`.  Or on most recent versions of other RDBMS, since it's mostly modern standard SQL. So not much of a challenge ;)  Oh wait, maybe there might be a small problem with the `ORDER BY`.  MSSQL complains if there's no `TOP` in a sub-query with an order by.

Comment: @LukStorms You can ignore the `order by` clause and give a try. Am doing `inner` join so results going to be same.

Comment: Check this out: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=fed4c4a9edb581fa571156b15558306b)*  Ok, the pivot syntax in mssql versus oracle isn't exactly the same.